# How to automatically add to the address book the addresses from emails I've received in Outlook Express 6?

Tags: email, outlook-express

I have quite a few saved emails in Outlook Express. Is there some way to automatically get the email addresses of their senders and add them to the address book? I can do some programming if it's necessary.